# Why is this proof incorrect? - $f(b) - f(a) = [Df(c)](b-a) = \nabla f(c) \cdot (b-a)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, partial-derivative

I'm currently a student in a Vector Calculus class, and received my exam back today. I plan to go to the professor's office hours, but I'd like to ask here (in case there's some blatantly obvious fault I'm missing). Not only do I not understand why I received no partial credit in this problem, but I don't understand why it's not *completely* correct. I'd really appreciate any insight. The problem statement is:

> Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R^n}$ with $a \neq b$. The segment $(a,b)$ in $\mathbb{R^n}$ is defined by: $$(a,b) := \{x \in \mathbb{R^n} | ~x = (1 - t)a + tb,~ t \in (0,1) \} $$
>
> Let $f: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be differentiable on $\mathbb{R^n}$. Use the Mean Value Theorem from single-variable calculus to show that there exists $c \in (a,b) \subset \mathbb{R^n}$ such that: $$f(b) - f(a) = [Df(c)](b-a) = \nabla f(c) \cdot (b-a)$$

Here's my proof:

We know $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R^n}$ (including on the interval $(a,b)$). Fix all elements in $x$ but one, call this element $x_i$ (that is, the $i^{th}$ element of $x$. Let $a_i < c_i < b_i$. By the mean value theorem, we know there is at least one $c_i$ such that the tangent at $c_i$ is parallel to the secant between $a_i$ and $b_i$. That is, there exists a $c_i$ such that:
$$\frac{f(b_i) - f(a_i)}{b_i - a_i} = \frac{\partial f(x_i)}{\partial c_i}$$
Multiplying by $(b_i - a_i)$ on both sides, we have:
$$f(b_i) - f(a_i) = \frac{\partial f(x_i)}{\partial c_i}(b_i - a_i)$$
We now fix all *other* elements in $x$ and, by the same process, arrive at the same result for every component of $x$. This gives us:
$$f(b) - f(a) = \left(\frac{\partial f(x_1)}{\partial c_1} + \frac{\partial f(x_2)}{\partial c_2}  + ... + \frac{\partial f(x_n)}{\partial c_n} \right)(b-a)$$
Note that the term on the right side of the equality is just $\nabla f(c) \cdot (b-a)$, so we know that there exists some $c$ such that: $$f(b) - f(a) = \nabla f(c) \cdot (b-a)$$

---

I have pretty much zero idea where I went wrong (but it's, apparently, *all* wrong). I'm very confused.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by $f(a_i)$. $f$ is fed vectors, not scalars.

Comment: How are you differentiating with respect to $c_i$?

Comment: You would need to show $c \in (a,b)$.  (And this construction of $c$ won't get that result.)

Comment: @PedroTamaroff Once you fix all of the elements in the vectors but one, $f$ only varies with a single element—the scalar.

I see where the differentiating w.r.t. thing is wrong; that's definitely a mess up on my part. I should've switched the $c_i$ and the $x_i$. 

It is assumed that $c \in (a,b)$, though; $c$ is just *some* point between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy mmh are you using that $f(b) = \sum_i f(b_i)$? am I following your flow of thoughts right?

Comment: @RicPed Yes. Is that incorrect? Maybe it'd be more accurate to say something like $\sum_i f_i(b_i)$

Comment: @AmagicalFishy i tried to work out an answer, even thought your idea of sums is not perfectly clear to me, I think this is the problem

Comment: Your restrictions of $f$ would be defined like $g_i(a) = f(x_1, \ldots x_{i-1}, a, x_{i+1}, \ldots x_n)$.  But note that gets you a different function $g_i$ at every set of $\{x_1, \ldots x_{i-1}, x_{i+1}, \ldots, x_n\}$.  So you can't determine $x_i$ to give $g_i$ a property, then determine $x_j$ in some other way, and assume the property holds for the $g_i$ which uses that new $x_j$.

Comment: "Fix all elements in $x$ but one, call this element $x_i$ (that is, the ith element of x)". Thus $x_i\in \mathbb{R}$. Later you take $f(x_i)$, but $f$ is a function on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

mmh, if $x_i$ means the $i$-th coordinate of $x$, then you can't calculate $f(x)$ as $\sum_i f(x_i)$. Think about $f(x,y)=xy$. $f(1,1)=1$ but $f(0,1)=f(1,0)=0$. It seems (not so clear) that you are assuming some linear property over $f$.

If this is the case, your reasoning is ruined from the beginning. In fact the right approach to this exercise is to combine the function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ with the function $h$ (the segment) $h: (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}^n$ to obtain a function $f(h(t)) :[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ for which the mean value theorem holds)

**I'll add some hints for a correct resolution** First of all, the mean value theorem holds for functions from $U \subseteq \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. (it's very easy to see - even graphically - that even in 2 dimensions there are lots of counterexamples). So the first step is building such function. The idea is to observe $f$ in the direction of the segment $g: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}^n \ g(t) = a+(b-a)t$, in this way, we can "consider" $f$ as a function from $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. The formalization of this reasoning is to make the composition of the two functions mentioned above to obtain $$g:= f(h(t)) : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R} $$. It's easy to see that $g$ is differentiable and you need to apply to it the mean value theorem. So the problem is, how to compute $g'$? Here comes in help the chain rule :)

Comment: The domain of $h$ is $(0,1)$, not $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @aschepler yeah, fixing it now. thanks^^ (only want to stress the fact that the domain is contained in $\mathbb{R}$)

Comment: Ah! Damnit, what a dumb mistake. I was so proud of this "proof", too. 

Would you be able to elaborate on the appropriate way to approach this? I'm not sure I understand the process.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy Yeah, it's all right if I post the general fact and I leave to you the calculations? I think it's better for you:) so let me edit the answer :)

Comment: Absolutely. A general idea is fine. 

Thanks. :)

Comment: I guess you actually need $h$ on the closed interval $[0,1]$.  And it doesn't actually break anything to just define it on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @AmagicalFishy hope it helps^^

Answer (score 2):

You are writing 
$$
\frac{f(b_i) - f(a_i)}{b_i - a_i} = \dots
$$ 
What is that supposed to mean? $f$ is a function of $n$ variables. You are setting the $i$th variable equal to $a_i$ and to $b_i$. What about all the other variables? What are they equal to in this formula? Are they still variable?

I'm sorry, I think you're out of luck. No partial credit here.

Comment: "Fix all elements in $x$ but one, call this element $x_i$ (that is, the $i^{th}$ element of x.)"

Comment: Show me how to do this for $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = x_1x_2^2x_3^3$ and $a = (1,2,3)$, $b = (2,3,4)$.

Comment: I'm... not sure I understand what you mean. If we fix, say, $x_2$ and $x_3$, then $f(x_1,x_2,x_3) = f(x_1)$.

Comment: PLease write down a formula in this particular case.

Comment: A formula for what? I'm afraid I'm... not quite sure what kind of formula you're looking for. I think there's some misunderstanding; perhaps I'm not grasping what it really means to *fix* some variables?

Comment: @AnagicalFishy - you are better off pursuing the hint that was given in the first answer (by Ric Ped) above. Regarding the current issue: Let's use the function $f$ of three variables that I wrote down further up. Now go ahead and "fix" $x_2$ and $x_3$. Can you compute $f(2)$? The result should be a number. What is the value?

Comment: Ah! It would just be $2 \times x_2^2 \times x_3^3$,  yes? I *think*  I see what you're saying—but my purpose in fixing the elements wasn't to calculate a particular value (that is, I think you're saying "*fixing* certain elements doesn't mean anything; when you try to evaluate the function, those elements are still variables). The purpose was to make statements regarding the derivatives of the function. I was attempting to piece together a  whole derivative from taking partial derivatives (wherein you "fix" all elements and take the derivative w/ respect to one of them).

Comment: What you can do is to consider the segments connecting $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$, $(b_1,a_2,a_3)$, $(b_1,b_2,a_3)$ and $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$. This way the argument presented in the question could make sense. But is still falls short of directly connecting $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ and $(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ with a straight segment and finding the midpoint there.